# Output of array redis

Tags: python, redis

Why i cant get output of data like just as letters?
My code:

```
dist = client.smembers(f"{usrid[user_id]}:{cit}")
print(dist)
```

My output:

```
{'9557'}
```

I tried `dist[0]` but this is useless. This is type set.
How can i get just number 9557 there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution to print at most one value:

```
for obj in dist:
    print(obj)
    break
```

Alternative:

```
print(next(iter(dist))
```

The second one will thrown an exception if `dist` is the empty set; the first one will do nothing. Both will print an arbitrary member if there is more than one.

If you know there is only one element, or if you don't mind them being printed one after another on the same line, you could use the even simpler

```
print(*dist)
```